# Conflicting project in Xtext mwe2 workflow

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext, mwe

I have a Xtext DSL that builds successfully from inside eclipse and maven and is included in a complex multi-plugin RCP application.

Yet, whenever the MWE2 workflow is executed the log is full of *warnings* of the form:

```
[INFO] 281  [main] WARN  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  
- Skipping conflicting project org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
at 'archive:file:/C:/userdir/.m2/repository/p2/
osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts/1.3.100.v20140407-1019
/org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts-1.3.100.v20140407-1019.jar!/'
and using 'archive:file:/C:/userdir/Documents/projects/projectdir/
resources/project/plugins
/org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.3.100.v20140407-1019.jar!/' instead.
```

Some of these warnings, like the above, are about a conflict between the local .m2 folder and a project folder, while others show a conflict between two project folders.

**Question**:

How do I get rid of these warnings?

My guess is that the project is misconfigured somehow including dependencies to some jars twice. 
Yet, at the moment I have no idea which dependencies are used by MWE2 during execution causing these warnings.

Is there any way to get an overview of the consulted dependencies or to debug this stuff?

Comment: I'd simply ignore it

Comment: Well, they are kind of annoying as they clutter the log. Also, when running the workflow printing the warnings alone takes around 30 seconds, so I thought this could also speed up the build job.

Comment: Can you file an issue at github.com/eclipse/xtext-core

Comment: Feel free to file a issue at eclipse/xtext-core at github